# Angular map over an array maps over each item of the array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the API that returns me data in the following format:

> {"data": [
>
> { path: "some path", site_link: "link", features:
> ['feature1', 'feature2'] }
>
> ... ]}

And next service

```
getSites(): Observable<Site[]> {
    return this.http.get<Site[]>(this.API_URL).pipe(
      map((site: SiteResponse): Site[] => {
        return site.data.map(e => new Site().deserialize(e));
      })
    );
  }
```

Site response interface

```
export interface SiteResponse {
  data: {
    path: string,
    siteLink: string,
    features: string[],
  }[];
}
```

That is a Site model

```
export class Site implements Deserializable {
  path: string;
  siteLink: string;
  features: Feature[];

  deserialize(input: any): this {
    Object.assign(this, input);
    console.log('----input', input);
    console.log('----this', this);
    console.log('----features', input.features);
    this.features = input.features.map(feature => new Feature().deserialize(feature));
    return this;
  }
}
```

Feature model

```
export class Feature implements Deserializable {
  feature: string;

  deserialize(input: any): this {
    Object.assign(this, input);
    return this;
  }
}
```

And that is what I get
[image]

I can't understand why it splits features contents meanwhile it should just create objects over each value of an array.

It works fine over 1st lever of the array as we can see that returned object is an instance of Site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As occurred string was transformed into array like object. Removing deserialization solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

features property in SiteResponse references string[] so it doesn't have feature property. Deserialize method in Feature model try to assign string to object properties. Try below.

```
export class Feature implements Deserializable {
  feature: string;

  deserialize(input: any): this {
    this.feature = input;
    return this;
  }
}
```